# {virtualFolder} in route config is not taking full path defined on the site defnition file

Tags: sitecore-api, routing, sitecore-mvc, custom-route

My current `Sitecore(9.0.2)` project have multisite implementation with URL structure as follows

- Url: [www.MainSite.com](http://www.MainSite.com) virtual folder:/
- Url: [www.MainSite.com/SubSite](http://www.MainSite.com/SubSite) virtual folder:/SubSite
- Url: [www.MainSite.com/SubSite/Site1](http://www.MainSite.com/SubSite/Site1) virtual folder:/SubSite/Site1
- Url: [www.MainSite.com/SubSite/Site2](http://www.MainSite.com/SubSite/Site2) virtual folder:/SubSite/Site2

We have to use a common Sitecore component for SubSite, Site1, and Site2.  the component has Ajax form posting and for this, I have added a single route entry for each of the APIs as follows:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
           name: "routeName",
           url: "{virtualFolder}/api/ContrrolerName/ActionName",
           defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "action", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The above routing is perfectly working for SubSite and when used on Site1 it is returning a 404 error during Ajax post.
However, it is working correctly when I removed SubSite from URL ie, [www.MainSite.com/Site1](http://www.MainSite.com/Site1).

So I understand that {virtualFolder} is not returning the path defined on siteconfig file. It is returning only the last part.

Anybody help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define separate routes for entries like that:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "routeNameVirtualFolder",
        url: "{virtualFolder}/api/ContrrolerName/ActionName",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                   );
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "routeNameVirtualSubFolder",
        url: "{virtualFolder}/{virtualSubFolder}/api/ContrrolerName/ActionName",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks @marek it is working